# Django with a custom view decorator causing "Page not redirecting properly"

Tags: django

I'm trying to write a custom decorator for a class-based view in Django. I want to check a particular condition, that a User is listed as the owner of a Scene object. I have the decorator written, and it works fine if the user is the owner - it allows the user to continue to the page properly. However if the user is not the owner, I get a "This page isn't redirecting properly" error.

Here is my decorator:

```
def scene_is_yours(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = kwargs.get('pk')
        scene = Scene.objects.get(id=pk)
        if not (scene.user.id == request.user.id):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('project-mine') 
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
```

Here is my view:

```
class SceneUpdateView(TemplateView):
    model = Scene
    fields = ['name', 'short_name', 'description']
    template_name = 'scene/edit.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    @method_decorator(scene_is_yours)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SceneUpdateView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

My traceback is just these two lines repeatedly:

```
[07/Jul/2015 22:10:35]"GET /accounts/login/?next=/scenes/1/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[07/Jul/2015 22:10:35]"GET /scenes/1/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

I've tried removing the login_required decorator, that had no effect. The user account I'm testing with is logged in, so I can't figure out why it's trying to send me to login and then back to the decorated view. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

try wraps decorator from functools  and maybe u shou rename function variable,
and Maybe you shoud use django urlresolvers:

```
from functools import wraps
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
...
    def scene_is_yours(view_function): 
        @wraps(view_function)
        def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
            pk = kwargs.get('pk')
            scene = Scene.objects.get(id=pk)
            if not (scene.user.id == request.user.id):
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project-mine')) 
            return view_function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrap
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. still get the same error, unfortunately.